# Buseman function is regular on manifolds without boundary containing a line?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, mg.metric-geometry

For an n-dim noncompact manifold M without boundary. Assume M contains a line $\gamma$.  For every point $p \in M$, let $\widetilde{p\gamma(t)}$ be the geodesic from p to $\gamma(t)$.

Choose a subsequence $t_i \to \infty$, such that $\widetilde{p\gamma(t_i)}$ converge to a ray $\gamma_p$ from p to infty which is asymptotic to $\gamma$ .

Consider the Buseman function $\beta (\cdot)=\lim_{t\to \infty}(t-|\gamma(t)\cdot|)$. Then along the ray $\gamma_p$, $\beta$ grows with the speed 1. So we get $\beta$ is regular at every point p in M with $|\nabla\beta(p)|=1$ ?

Comment: what if you have two (different) rays from p asymptotic to \gamma?

Comment: @valeri:Choose any one of them.

Comment: then your regular function would have two gradients?

Comment: I didn't get the question. Busemann function clearly might have many critical points. But it does has gradient of unit length almost everywhere.